# Numberformatter without rounding. One behaviour in Xcode project another in playground

Tags: swift, nsnumberformatter

I am experiencing some weird behaviour using the `NumberFormatter`.

The following code:

```
let str = "5.99"
let doub = Double(str)
let nsnum = NSNumber(floatLiteral: doub!)
let formatter = NumberFormatter()

formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "da_DK") as Locale!
formatter.currencySymbol = ""

let forStr = formatter.string(from: nsnum)
```

does not return the same result when run in my Xcode project and when run in a playground.swift file.

In the playground `forStr` is "5.99" in the project `forStr` is "6". The behaviour from the playground is the one I'm after.

I have tried adding:

```
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.roundingMode = .down
```

but they have no effect in my project.

Any ideas as of why this is happening?

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem, `forStr` is `"5,99 "` in both Playground and compiled project.

Comment: Hi @MartinR, maybe its a bug in my project?

Comment: formatter.roundingMode = .down worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the round function for this.

Say you need two digits precision. Then you need to multiply by 100, then round it, and then divide the result with 100.

```
let a = 5.9999
let b = Double(round(100*a)/100)
print(b)  //Output will be 6.0
```

Comment: Hi @Anil I think you misunderstood my question. I do not want to round the number.